# jQuery - Compare data-attr to search term

Tags: jquery

I am trying to compare a data-attribute to a search term like so:

```
var searchArea = $('#indexContainer');
var searchVal = $('#search').val();
var items = $('.processLink');

var links;

$('#search').keyup(function() {
  // on search input key up

  //for each .processLink
  $.each(items, function(index, value) {
    //get the selector
    var selected = $(value);

    //get the keywords
    var keywords = selected.data('keywords');

    //console.log(selected.attr('id'));

    $("#" + selected.attr('id') + ":contains('" + searchVal + "')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
  });

});
```

so if I have a few divs like these

```
<div id="div1" class="processLink" data-keywords="div one cat dog"></div>
<div id="div2" class="processLink" data-keywords="div blade cow horse"></div>
<div id="div3" class="processLink" data-keywords="div camera bag"></div>
<div id="div4" class="processLink" data-keywords="div"></div>
```

Then I just want to check on the key up whether the search term entered in to 
search input matches any of the terms in data-keyword attribute and if they do then only show the .processLink divs which have the related words and hide the rest. I know I currently have it trying to underline, that was just a test

Hopefully that makes some kind of sense

Comment: Please post all the related code so people will be able to help you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues with the above code.

1. Value of the input should be fetched inside `keyup`
2. You don't need `each` in case you have a jQuery collection `$('.processLink');` already defined.
3. `:contains(` checks for content inside the `div` and not its attributes. You would need *attribute contains selector* - `[attribute *=..]` for this.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk7pdc7/12/)**

---

```
$(function(){
    var $divs = $('.processLink');
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var searchVal = this.value;
        $divs.css("text-decoration", "none");
        $divs.filter('[data-keywords*="'+searchVal+'"]').css("text-decoration", "underline");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
$("#" + selected.attr('id') + ":contains('"+searchVal+"')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

to:

```
if (typeof keywords === 'string' && keywords.indexOf(searchVal) !== -1) {
    selected.css("text-decoration", "underline");
}
else {
    selected.css("text-decoration", "none");
}
```

By the way, you will probably need a fresh `searchVal` valule on each key up, you might need to move `var searchVal = $('#search').val();` into the `keyup` callback, or alternatively use the `event` argument in the callback like `event.currentTarget.value`.

Comment: I get an error for undefined keywords : TypeError: keywords is undefined

I assume this is because some of them do not have keywords attached yet, how can I handle this to skip to the next element if it doesnt have any

Comment: I edited my answer, and added a verification that `keywords` is a string.

Comment: that seems to work, however once you have deleted out of the search box the underline remains. How can I remove that styling once a match isn't found

Comment: Edited my answer once again.

Answer (score 0):

$('.classname tagname[data-id=' + vlaue + ']').parent().addClass("addclassname");

Comment: When posting answers on SO please provide an explanation for your solution along with the code.